# Can a Linux router utilize its congestion control ops on internet traffic from other computers or does it have to act as a reverse proxy?

Tags: linux, routing, reverse-proxy, tcp

I was wondering if a small raspberry pi like device could utilize Linux's congestion control algorithms on any internet connection on a different windows/linux pc. Is turning the linux device into a router sufficient enough (because AFAIK routers only work on OSI Layer 3 traffic and TCP congestion control ops are solely on Layer 4) or do I have to configure it as a reverse proxy?

The device is going to be between a router and a pc. A LAN cable from pc to the device will be setup, after which the device will be connected to the modem through another cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To some extent, but you probably need a device with two Ethernet ports, or it will be a gross hack (as in, I've had that working, but it had interesting problems).

What you can do on a router is limit your upstream bandwidth to ~95% of what is truly available so packets queue up in the router instead of the modem, where they can still be rearranged.

A setup I've been rather happy with just had two priorities, "high" for small packets and "low" for large ones, with 80% of available bandwidth going to small packets if both tiers have data queued, because that lets acknowledges for received data go in front, allowing the other side to send more data to you.

In general, traffic shaping needs to be done before the slow link, so shaping your downstream needs to happen on the ISP side. There is "ingress policing", where you apply a traffic shaper to incoming traffic, but the effects of that are a lot less pronounced because all this affects are feedback mechanisms (i.e. we pretend that the link is worse than it truly is, causing individual connections to back off, which gives better overall performance).

Comment: the device has 2 ethernet ports so no problem there. so configuring it as just a router is enough? can that affect layer 4?

Comment: The only way that the TCP layer is affected is if the router is configured with a Random Early Drop (RED) scheduler in ECN mode -- then it will notify the destination with a specific value in the DiffServ field of the IP header, and TCP can react to it by setting ECN flags. My expectation would be that this is unnecessary in most home setups, and configuring a HTB queuing discipline for the upstream port as I described is sufficient. If you want to go the extra mile, set up RED in ECN mode on the downstream port as well -- but that will also need shaping or RED does nothing.

Comment: Apologies for the belated response, thank you for your answer